# ANTLR4 - Syntax error on '#' (alternative rule label)

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

I have made a grammar that will be used with ANTLR4 with the following definition for expressions:

```
// Expressions
Expr : Integer               # Expr_Integer
    | Float                  # Expr_Float
    | Double                 # Expr_Double
    | String                 # Expr_String
    | Variable               # Expr_Variable
    | FuncCall               # Expr_FuncCall
    | Expr Op_Infix Expr     # Expr_Infix
    | Op_Prefix Expr         # Expr_Prefix
    | Expr Op_Postfix        # Expr_Postfix
    | Expr 'is' Id           # Expr_Is
    | 'this'                 # Expr_This
    | Expr '?' Expr ':' Expr # Expr_Ternary
    | '(' Expr ')'           # Expr_Bracketed
    ;
```

I added the labels so that I could easily differentiate between the different expression types when analysing the generated syntax tree. However, ANTLR4 throws the following error for every single one of the above lines (excluding the one with the comment):

```
error(50): Ash.g4:88:19: syntax error: '#' came as a complete surprise to me while looking for lexer rule element
```

Line 88 is the final rule alternative ( `'(' Expr ')'` )

I have look through the [documentation](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Parser+Rules#ParserRules-AlternativeLabels) and various online examples and my syntax seems correct.

What could be causing the error to be thrown?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Antlr, rules beginning with an uppercase letter are lexer rules, and those beginning with an lowercase letter are parser rules. Antlr uses these definitions a lot to define what you can and cannot do. Usually, the lexer is faster to proccess but less powerful than the parser.

In your case, `Expr` should definitely be a parser rule, as basically every other rule you have referenced there. Changing it to `expr` should match the expected behavior.

As a rule of thumb, lexer rules are to be used only when there is no context, it doesn't matter what is next to the generated token. Things like numeric constants, string constants, identifiers and such.

Comment: Thanks! This little "feature" is slightly annoying, but I guess we have to put up with the designers' choices. It is a good piece of software after all.